# Filtering an Array within an Array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import {
  StaticQuery,
  grahpql, 
  Link 
} from "gatsby"
import {
  StyledFilter,
  StyledLine
} from "./styled"

class Filter extends Component {

  render() {

    const { data } = this.props
    const categories = data.allPrismicProjectCategory.edges.map((cat, index) => {
      return (
        <a
          key={index}
          onClick={() => this.props.setFilterValue(cat.node.uid)}
        >
          {cat.node.data.category.text}
        </a>
      )
    })

    return (
      <StyledFilter>
        <div>
          Filter by<StyledLine />
          <a
            // onClick={() => {this.props.filterProjects("all")}}
          >
            All
          </a>
          {categories}
        </div>
        <a onClick={this.props.changeGridStyle}>{this.props.gridStyleText}</a>
      </StyledFilter>
    )
  }

}

export default props => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
    query {
      allPrismicProjectCategory {
        edges {
          node {
            uid
            data {
              category {
                text
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `}
    render={data => <Filter data={data} {...props} />}
    />
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I am working on a React App with Gatsby and Prismic that has a project page. By default it lists all projects but at the page's top appears a filter to select by category (just a bunch of `<a>` tags).

My Page consists of a `<Filter />` component as well as several `<GridItem />` components I am mapping over and load some props from the CMS.

The part I am struggling with is the filtering by category.

When my page component mounts it adds all projects into my `filteredItems` state.

When a user is clicking on a filter at the top it set's my default `filterValue` state from `"all"` to the according value.
After that I'll first need to map over the array of projects and within that array I'll need to map over the categories (each project can belong to multiple categories).

My idea is basically if a value (the `uid`) matches my new `this.state.filterValue` it returns the object and add's it to my `filteredItems` state (and of course delete the one's not matching this criteria).

This is what my page component looks like (cleaned up for better readability, full code in the snippet at the bottom):

```
class WorkPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      filterValue: "all",
      filteredItems: []
    }
    this.filterProjects = this.filterProjects.bind(this)
  }

  filterProjects = (filterValue) => {
    this.setState({ filterValue: filterValue }, () => 
      console.log(this.state.filterValue)
    )
    // see a few of my approaches below
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      filteredItems: this.props.data.prismicWork.data.projects
    })
  }

  render() {

    const projectItems = this.props.data.prismicWork.data.projects && this.props.data.prismicWork.data.projects.map((node, index) => {
      const item = node.project_item.document["0"].data
      const categories = node.project_item.document["0"].data.categories.map(cat => {
        return cat.category_tag.document["0"].uid
      })

      return (
        <GridItem
          key={index}
          categories={categories}
      moreContentProps={moreContentProps}
        />
      )
    })

    return (
      <LayoutDefault>
        <Filter
          filterProjects={this.filterProjects}
        />
    {projectItems}
      </LayoutDefault>

    )
  }

}
```

I tried so many things, I can't list all of them, but here are some examples:

This approach always returns an array of 10 objects (I have 10 projects), sometimes the one's that don't match the `this.state.filterValue` are empty objects, sometimes they still return their whole data.

```
let result = this.state.filteredItems.map(item => {
  return item.project_item.document["0"].data.categories.filter(cat => cat.category_tag.document["0"].uid === this.state.filterValue)
})
console.log(result)
```

After that I tried to filter directly on the parent item (if that makes sense) and make use of `indexOf`, but this always console logged an empty array...

```
let result = this.state.filteredItems.filter(item => {
  return (item.project_item.document["0"].data.categories.indexOf(this.state.filterValue) >= 0)
})
console.log(result)
```

Another approach was this (naive) way to map over first the projects and then the categories to find a matching value. This returns an array of undefined objects.

```
let result = this.state.filteredItems.map(item => {
  item = item.project_item.document["0"].data.categories.map(attachedCat => {
    if (attachedCat.category_tag.document["0"].uid === this.state.filterValue) {
      console.log(item)
    }
  })
})
console.log(result)
```

Other than that I am not even sure if my approach (having a `filteredItems` state that updates based on if a filter matches the according category) is a good or "right" React way.

Pretty stuck to be honest, any hints or help really appreciated.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import LayoutDefault from "../layouts/default"
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components"
import Hero from "../components/hero/index"
import GridWork from "../components/grid-work/index"
import GridItem from "../components/grid-item/index"
import Filter from "../components/filter/index"

class WorkPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      filterValue: "all",
      filteredItems: [],
      isOnWorkPage: true,
      showAsEqualGrid: false
    }
    this.filterProjects = this.filterProjects.bind(this)
    this.changeGridStyle = this.changeGridStyle.bind(this)
  }

  changeGridStyle = (showAsEqualGrid) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showAsEqualGrid: !prevState.showAsEqualGrid,
      isOnWorkPage: !prevState.isOnWorkPage
    }))
  }

  filterProjects = (filterValue) => {
    this.setState({ filterValue: filterValue }, () => 
    console.log(this.state.filterValue)
    )


    let result = this.state.filteredItems.filter(item => {
      return (item.project_item.document["0"].data.categories.toString().indexOf(this.state.filterValue) >= 0)
    })
    console.log(result)
  } 

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      filteredItems: this.props.data.prismicWork.data.projects
    })
  }

  render() {

    const projectItems = this.props.data.prismicWork.data.projects && this.props.data.prismicWork.data.projects.map((node, index) => {
      const item = node.project_item.document["0"].data

      const categories = node.project_item.document["0"].data.categories.map(cat => {
        return cat.category_tag.document["0"].uid
      })

      return (
        <GridItem
          key={index}
          isSelected="false"
          isOnWorkPage={this.state.isOnWorkPage}
          isEqualGrid={this.state.showAsEqualGrid}
          projectURL={`/work/${node.project_item.uid}`}
          client={item.client.text}
          tagline={item.teaser_tagline.text}
          categories={categories}
          imageURL={item.teaser_image.squarelarge.url}
          imageAlt={item.teaser_image.alt}
        />
      )
    })

    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={{ mode: "light" }}>
        <LayoutDefault>
          <Hero
            introline="Projects"
            headline="Art direction results in strong brand narratives and compelling content."
          />
          {/* {filteredResult} */}
          <Filter
            filterProjects={this.filterProjects}
            changeGridStyle={this.changeGridStyle}
            gridStyleText={this.state.showAsEqualGrid ? "Show Flow" : "Show Grid"}
          />
          <GridWork>
            {projectItems}
          </GridWork>
        </LayoutDefault>
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }

}

export default WorkPage

export const workQuery = graphql`
  query Work {
    prismicWork {
      data {
        page_title {
          text
        }

        # All linked projects
        projects {
          project_item {
            uid

            # Linked Content
            document {
              type
              data {
                client {
                  text
                }
                teaser_tagline {
                  text
                }
                teaser_image {
                  url
                  alt
                  xlarge {
                    url
                  }
                  large {
                    url
                  }
                  medium {
                    url
                  }
                  squarelarge {
                    url
                  }
                  squaremedium {
                    url
                  }
                  squaresmall {
                    url
                  }
                }

                categories {
                  category_tag {
                    document {
                      uid
                      data {
                        category {
                          text
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet (Ctrl+M) with the whole component code and a sample of your projects array/object that you're trying to filter, please?

Comment: Thanks for getting back @anarchist912. Do you mean like that? A sample of how the arrays are structured is visible via the graphql query.

Comment: Yeah, that's good. I'll write you an answer. Within the snippet editor you can set the flag 'hide snippet by default' at the bottom left. That way you question stays more readable for future readers. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are at least two things.

1. In your `filterProjects()` you're first setting `state.filterValue` and then you use it in `filteredItems.filter()`. That might not work, because React does not execute `setState()` immediately always, to optimize performance. So you're probably filtering against the previous value of `state.filterValue`. Instead just use `filterValue`, which you pass into `filterProjects()`.

```
setFilterValue = (filterValue) => {
    this.setState({filterValue}) // if key and variable are named identically, you can just pass it into setState like that
}

// arrow function without curly braces returns without return statement
filterProjects = (projects, filterValue) =>
    projects.filter(item => item.project_item.document[0].data.categories.toString().includes(filterValue))
```

2. You should **`return`** the result from `filterProjects()`, because you need to render based on the `filteredItems` then, of course. But actually it's not necessary to put the filter result into `state`. You can apply the `filterProjects()` on the `props` directly, right within the `render()`. That's why you should return them. Also separate `setState` into another function which you can pass into your `<Filter/>` component.

And a *recommendation*: Use destructuring to make your code more readable. For you and anyone else working with it.

```
render() {
    const { projects } = this.props.data.prismicWork.data // this is
    const { filterValue } = this.state                    // destructuring
    if (projects != undefined) {
        this.filterProjects(projects, filterValue).map((node, index) => {
        // ...

// Filter component
<Filter filterProjects={this.setFilterValue} />
```

> That way you trigger a rerender by setting the `filterValue`, because it
>   resides in `this.state`, and the render function depends on
>   `this.state.filterValue`.

Please try that out and tell me if there is another problem.

Comment: Hey @anarchist912. I really appreciated your detailed write up and explanation. Unfortunately it does not change my `filteredItems` state and still has the initial array. It does not return any errors in the console, it does not change the state array either though...

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please add your <Filter/> component to the snippet?

Comment: And check what `filterProjects()` returns? You need to render based on the `filteredItems` then, of course. But actually it's not necessary to put the filter result into `state`. You can apply the `filterProjects()` on the props directly, right within the render(), before mapping them. That's why you should return them. Didn't mention that. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks once again a ton @anarchist912 — just added my Filter component snippet above and will now look into your further suggestions...

Comment: THIS IS NOT A WAY TO FILTER

Comment: @kishorekingmaker explaining your argument would make it even more convincing than the use of the caps lock button. :P

Comment: @ChristophBerger If you pass `this.setFilterValue` like this: `<Filter filterProjects={this.setFilterValue} />` then you need to call it in the Filter component with `this.props.filterProjects()` not `this.props.setFilterValues()` — just in case that is not clear.

Comment: @anarchist912 Ok, just solved it, not exactly the way you suggested it, but it's extremely close. My code is a bit of a mess now (as it's sometimes when you're playing around almost endlessly) ;-), cleaning it up now... And if you are interested or if someone might be reading this in the future I'll post my bits later.

Whatever, without you I could not have solved it. Really appreciate your support and help as well as your tips on React (e.g. destructuring).

Will upvote your answer. Cheers again!

Comment: Would still be interested why @kishorekingmaker feels this way is not a good idea...

Comment: @ChristophBerger I guess in your use case its okay. If you're filtering large datasets, this can be too much for the browser and you should actually do the filtering server side. As long as you don't have any performance issues, it's fine though, I'd say.

Comment: If it were more projects I'd do it from the backend anyway, in this case we are talking about 20 to 25 items only.